# Is there a way to fill a "donut hole" of 0 values in a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I'm working with some images, using gray intensity values in data frames. I manipulate the raw values a handful of ways, and let's just say I end up with a data frame that looks like this:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 3 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 

0 0 0 0 0 1 2 1 3 1 5 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 1 3 1 1 1 4 3 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 1 1 5 2 **0** 1 1 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 5 1 1 **0** 2 1 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 1 3 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Note the bolded 0 values, which are the only 0s surrounded by non-zero values on all sides. What I'm hoping to do is convert the 0s in those locations, and only those locations, to 1 (for example), without disrupting all the outer 0s.

I've looked through the documentation but I'm not sure how--if it's possible--to tell pd.replace what conditions must be met to replace a given 0. Does anyone have any suggestions? Sorry for the formatting - new here.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldnt bother with a pandas dataframe. I would convert it to a two-dimensional python list and work with it from there.
First i converted your dataframe to a list: `df.values.tolist()`
Then i used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64341287/find-surrounding-elements-in-a-2d-list) question to find all neighbouring values and from there it was smooth sailing

```py
def checkNeighboursForNull(arrayList, rowIdx, colIdx) -> bool:
    values = []
    for index_y, value_y in enumerate(arrayList):
        for index_x, value_x in enumerate(value_y):
            if (rowIdx, colIdx) != (index_y, index_x):
                if (abs(index_x - colIdx) < 2) and (abs(index_y - rowIdx) < 2):
                    values.append(value_x)
    if 0 in values:
        return False
    return True
```

This code returns a boolean whether the current `0` that it found has any neighbouring zeros

```py
arrayList = [[1, 2, 3, 4],
             [4, 4, 0, 0],
             [7, 8, 9, 2]]

for rowIdx, row in enumerate(arrayList):
    for colIdx, col in enumerate(row):
        if col == 0:
            isNullInNeighbours = checkNeighboursForNull(arrayList, rowIdx, colIdx)
            arrayList[rowIdx][colIdx] = 1 if isNullInNeighbours else 0
        
print(arrayList)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for taking to time to have a crack at this. Considering the very good point the chrslg made, it strikes me that this would work for individual 0s surrounded by non-zeros, but (correct me if I'm wrong) would not adjust any 0s that may occur beside one another. It's rare that I end up with a single "embedded" 0 pixel (likely a combination of my bit depth vs. background correction), so small "islands" of 0s would be ignored. I think as suggested below, it may be a better idea for me to feed this into an image-specific tool.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. This would only work with individual 0s (Thats how your question for formed though). And i also agree that using an image-specific tool would be better, so try going in that direction

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'am missing serious context element, this is really not what dataframes in general, and pandas is particular, is made for.

This is a task for an image processing algorithm. Like openCV. Good news is OpenCV's images are just numpy arrays. And you can easily get one of those from a pandas DataFrame.

For example, you could try something in the effect of

```py
import cv2

image=(df.values==0).astype(np.uint8) # ndarray, as 8 bit image
# Returns the number of 0 connected areas + 1 for the non-0 area (not connected). And a mask image, with 0 in the non-0 areas (sounds paradoxical, but that is just because I asked for components of df.values==0 image), and an id of the area in the rest. Just try it to see.
ncomp, mask=cv2.connectedComponents(image)
# Iterate all areas to find out which ones are non connected to the border (which is the same as not being entirely surrounded by non-0)
# Note that component 0 is the one of non-0 area, so we don't want it
for i in range(1,ncomp):
    if (mask[0]==i).any() or (mask[-1]==i).any() or (mask[:,0]==i).any() or (mask[:,-1]==i).any():
        continue # This component is connected to one border
    df.values[mask==i]=1
```

That is, if I understood correctly what you meant by "surrounded by non 0". I take it was the area that has to be surrounded by non 0, not each of the 0. (Otherwise, your example would not be valid, since even the 2 central 0 have each other as neighbors).

Another possibility (depending on what you are really trying to do), is, still with OpenCV, to use [mathematical morphology](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html). Specifically closing operator (or opening, if you want to focus on binary image of 0 values, as before). It is not exactly the same as before. But if your 0 areas are in practice small holes in big non-zero areas, may be this is what you are looking for.

Comment: The point you raised is an extremely good one, and I understand now that I misphrased my original question; I do indeed want to look for "islands" of any number of connected 0s that have a complete outer lining of non-0s. In image processing programs I've used previously (even ImageJ, I believe), I've seen "hole fill" parameters so I was wondering if that sort of algorithm existed for data frames.

Thanks so much for directing me to those image-specific resources. I think that's the right path to go down for this objective.